# Image in launchscreen storyboard not visible despite matching width/height constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

I've got a `UIImageView` in my `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file that I want to fill the view, so I command-click-drag from the image to the containing view and select `Equal Widths` and `Equal Heights`. When run, the background image isn't visible (all I see is the logo image).

Here is the scene hierarchy with constraints:

[image: Scene hierarchy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You haven't set any constraints which define the origin of your background** image. This may cause your image to be misplaced. Don't you have any layout errors or warnings in this view controller?

For the background image I recommend you to **replace equal width and height** to the superview with **leading, trailing, top and bottom** constraints to the superview.

This is the example solution

[image: example layout solution]

Answer (score 1):

You have specified the size of your view, but not *where* it should be positioned.

Constrain the top edge of the image view with the top edge of its superview and do the same with their left edges, respectively.

While there are several other possibilities to achieve the same layout with constraints, it is always necessary to **constrain the position of the view**.